# How to find limit of sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

How to find limit of this sequence ?

$a_n = ln(\frac{2n+1}{2n}) \sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt[k]{k} $

Comment: It would improve this Question if you gave some context, like what sort of rules you were studying that this might be intended to illustrate (or in other ways to let Readers know what your perspective is for this exercise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$n\ln(1+\frac1{2n})$$ converges towards $\dfrac12$.

$$\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt[k]k$$ converges by Cesaro (-Stolz) to the same limit as $\sqrt[n]n$, which one knows converges to $1$.